# emulator open after reinstall GPU drive

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gpu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS73b.png)
i cant open emulator in android studio
but it is open when i reinstall GPU driver

storge is good and all update install in pc
when i reinstall GPU driver the emulator start
and when i restart the pc